# Yii2 how to change precision for double type while migrating

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I'm using MySQL database and trying to change column precision. I need to restrict numbers to 2 zeros afrer comma. But after execute this code: `$this->alterColumn(offer::tableName(), 'price', $this->double(8.2)->null());` column precision in database is empty.

[image]

Result:
[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the numbers to 2 decimal numbers you should use fixed-point type like [`DECIMAL(8, 2)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html).
In migration:

```php
$this->decimal(8, 2)
```

Floating point types like `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` allows only limited ways to set precision. There is support for `FLOAT(M, D)` and `DOUBLE(M, D)` syntax in MySQL. But, it's pretty much just an alias and you will always end with 4-byte float or 8-byte double. [See documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html)